# How to remove magento's categories sidebar navigation?

Tags: magento-1.9.1

I want to remove the category listing in the category view from my magento site. I got the top menu and the sidebar one is redundant.

Answer (score 1):

**This was dispaly in left sidebar using this code**

```
<reference name="left">
 <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/navigation/left_nav.phtml" />
</reference>
```

**So remove using local.xml**

```
<default>
    <reference name="left">
          <remove name="catalog.leftnav">
    </reference>
</default>
```

**Or then add catalog/layer_view block where you want to, but change the name**

```
<block type="catalog/layer_view" name="yourname.catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/layer/view.phtml"/>
```

Comment: In my categories page left navigation how can I order attributes?  @ravi patel